# Esitmate of minimal of a function changed after transforming the variable

Tags: probability, bayesian, random-variable, density-function, markov-chain-montecarlo

I want to perform MCMC or HMC for solving minimization problem of a function $f(x)$, then define the corresponding density $$g(x) = \exp\left(-f(x)\right)$$
Because the function of the future apply is only valid in a finite domain, I perform a variable transform by
$$y = \log(x - lb) - \log(ub - x)$$,
where $lb$ and $ub$ is the lower and upper boundary. Through the Jacobian formula
$$G(y) = \frac{g(x)}{|J(x)|}$$
written in logarithmic form
$$\log\left(G(y)\right) = -f(x) - \log\left(|J(x)|\right)$$
A new function is used for MCMC
$$h(x) = -\log\left(G(y)\right) = f(x) + \log\left(|J(x)|\right)$$
I thought the minimal location of $h(x)$ is the same as $f(x)$, but the result shows it's not. I'm confused why they're different, is the jacobian formula completely correct or I misunderstand something?

Below is the McCormick function, the minimal is at (-0.55, -1.55), but the minimal of $h(x)$ is at (-0.27, -1.32). Another figure is along x axis when y = -1.55

[image: McCormick function]
[image: McCormick function]

Comment: Dividing by the Jacobian virtually guarantees you will shift the locations of the extrema.  This happens even for univariate variables: compare the extrema of a Normal and the associated Lognormal distribution, for instance.